# Remove access to drive "Properties" in My Computer

Tags: windows-7, group-policy

I'm attempting to lock down a Windows 7 build but I've noticed that users (In this case, students) can highlight a drive and get to the properties menu. I'd like to disable this if possible.

I normally use the following GPO:

> User Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Windows
> Explorer\Remove Windows Explorer's default context menu

Which also disables the "Properties" button, but occasionally customers ask for this to be left enabled. So, is there a way to do both?

[image: Drive Properties]

Answer (score 3):

Why bother with hiding things? I don't feel like hiding things, typically, accomplishes much of anything useful and usually creates "make work".

Make sure that the NTFS and/or share permissions on the shared folder are such that the student users can't actually make any changes to permissions and let them look at the "Properties" sheets all they want.

Comment: I don't *disagree*, and this question was really more out of curiosity as I couldn't find anything else on the net. But, in my experience, kids will click and play with anything they can find - so it's in my interest to provide the customer with a solution that contains minimal fuss!